# Problem in 5v pump

Tags: motor, dc-motor, npn, darlington, fluid-pump

I connected the pump to tip122 darlington transistor to control it via serial port.
but the pump doesn't work. instead , it makes sound.
how can i make the pump work
the circuit of the tip122 :
[image]

the circuit of the power supply :
[image]



the features of the pump :

Mini Water Pump, Northbear Ultra-quiet Mini DC 3-6V 120L/H Brushless Motor Submersible Water Pump

```
Material: plastic+electronic components
DC Voltage: 2.5-6V
Flow rate: 80-120L/H
Power: 0.4-1.5W
Maximum lift: 40-110cm 
Outside diameter of water outlet: 7.5mm
Inside diameter of water outlet: 4.7mm 
Diameter:Approx. 24mm
Length:Approx. 45mm
Height:Approx. 33mm
Material:engineering plastic
Driving mode: brushless dc design, magnetic driving
Continuous working life of 500 hours
```

photo of the pump :

[image]

Comment: What's your intent with D4? All it's doing is wasting some power and dropping probably almost a volt ...

Comment: After you remove D4, can you measure the voltages on your transistor? Base to emitter and collector to emitter.

Comment: emitter = 0v
collector = 4.9v
base (when digital pin = 1) = 0.2v
@MathKeepsMeBusy
TIP122 datasheet :
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/323272/Motorola/TIP122/1

Comment: @KiroloesAmir it _looks_ like your MCU pin is not providing enough current to drive the base of your transistor. Are you sure you have the right pins connected? Are you sure your MCU has that pin "on"? Perahps that pin is open-drain? what kind of mcu and which pin?

Comment: Pin 3 in Port 3 AT89S52 MCU @MathKeepsMeBusy
the pin provides 5v but after adding 330 ohm resistor , the voltage decreases to less than 0.5v

Comment: Always connect a diode in parallel to the pump to catch the inductive current when the pump turns off. Otherwise, your transistor will blow out. You will replace it, and then it will blow out again. This may be your problem.

Comment: Apart from fixing your switching circuit, you need to control this with a GPIO outputting a steady level, not a "serial port" outputting a coded series of pulses

Comment: All 89S52 I/O ports are  essentiallly "open collector" ports with internal pull-up resistors - the internal pull-up resistor may not be able to supply enough current to fully turn on your transistor.

Comment: Are you doing this on a bread-board, or do you have a PCB? If a breadboard, do you have other GPIO pins available? Also, if on a breadboard, if you disconnect the GPIO pin from the base resistor, and instead connect the 5V supply through a larger resistor, say 2.2K if you have one, to the base of the transistor, does the motor start? Pleases don't try this unless you are sure you understand what I am asking.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy the motor started rotating when i connected the base of the transistor to 5v supply through 1k ohm resistor

Comment: @KiroloesAmir Great! That means that 4-5mA into the base starts the motor. With the 330 Ohm resistor still disconnected, the voltage on the GPIO pin is still near 5V?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy when the 1k ohm resistor be connected to the GPIO , the voltage of GPIO is still less than 0.5v 
when there is no resistors connected to the GPIO , the GPIO voltage is 5v

Comment: If you feel comfortable with this suggestion, connect the 1K resistor to the base, as before, the other end to 5V. Then _also_ connect the 330 Ohm to the base, the other end to the GPIO. Motor should run. Then programmatically turn _off_ the GPIO pin, and see if the motor stops.  Do you have any pins available on other ports? On the 89S52, port 0 can handle greater currents with pull-up resistors than the other ports. Something to think about.